# Translate website to any specific language, on page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom-events, google-translate, google-translator-toolkit

Anybody have any idea how to translate a web page into any language using Google translate when it loads?

I don't want a drop down menu, I just want to convert the website into a specific language when it loads. I have tried many things from 
http://code.google.com/p/jquery-translate/ but all in vain. Any good suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 17):

```
<!--
  This code will translate page contents automatically (without user input)
  Settings located at line 9, current script will translate english to estonian
-->
<style>#google_translate_element,.skiptranslate{display:none;}body{top:0!important;}</style>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
        new google.translate.TranslateElement({
            pageLanguage: 'en', 
            includedLanguages: 'et', 
            autoDisplay: false
        }, 'google_translate_element');
        var a = document.querySelector("#google_translate_element select");
        a.selectedIndex=1;
        a.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

From this gist:
https://gist.github.com/artturik/15bed885bcec6faa95eb73acb2e2ae54

Answer (score 8):

From [Google Translate Help](http://support.google.com/translate/#2643150):

> To create a link that automatically translates your Website
>   Translator-enabled page without prompting your users, use the
>   parameter `#googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE)`.
>
> For example, the link 
>   http://translate.google.com/support/#googtrans(en|fr) automatically
>   translates the page http://translate.google.com/support/ into French.

Comment: It worked for me. But the page is first showing up in English and translating after a few seconds. Is there a way I can hide the page till it translates?

Answer (score 5):

you can get you google translator code from https://translate.google.com by giving you website  URL.

**LIKE THIS:**

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ar', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: actually i don't need this drop down thing, i just want,my page which is in English automatically translate into swedish on page load event.

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the google translate is that it works with some time lag. I tried it with 10,100 and 1000ms but only the 1000ms(means 1 second) worked perfectly. I hope this one does the job for you.

Style the google_translate_element as display:none to hide it.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en',
        includedLanguages: 'en,es',
      }, 'google_translate_element');
      
      setTimeout(function() {
        // Set the default language to Spanish
        var selectElement = document.querySelector('#google_translate_element select');
        selectElement.value = 'es';
        selectElement.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
      }, 1000);
    }
  </script>
```

This will translate the page to Spanish ("es") on page load.

Answer (score 0):

it is working code currently it is being used

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/#en/hi/Hello"></script>
</head>

<style>
body > .skiptranslate {
    //display: none;
}

.goog-te-banner-frame.skiptranslate {
    display: none !important;
    } 
body {
    top: 0px !important; 
    }

@media print {
  #google_translate_element {display: none;}
}
</style>

<body>
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>

<p>This example displays a simple translate button, with no text.</p>
<p>This example displays a simple translate button, with no text.</p>

<div class="notranslate">
<p >This is a paragraph.</p>
<p >
A particle is kept at rest at the top of a sphere of diameter \(42 m\). When disturbed slightly,
it slides down. At what height \( h \) from the bottom, the particle will leave the sphere <br\>
(a) \( 14m \)
(b) \( 16m \)
(c) \( 35m \)
(d) \( 70m \)

</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

It will translate you web page content. if you don't want to translate any particular div content just use class notranslate. then google translator will not translate that div content.