# Automatic translation does not work in coordinator after redirect page

Tags: javascript, php, google-translate

Hello friends am new in php and i want to use google translate on my website So I am using the google translate tool for my website- I am setting it up via: https://translate.google.com/manager/website/
    my website data is an Arabic but i want to translate it is by default an English.if i choose language from drop down so it is working but i want to default translate it is an English  do not need to choose language.and one more think when i choose language it is work but when my page redirect another page in this case it is not working
     here is my code

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">


function googleTranslateElementInit()
{
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'ar', includedLanguages: 'ar,en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.FloatPosition.TOP_LEFT}, 'google_translate_element');
}

     $(window).load(function ()
     {
     setTimeout(function ()
     {
     if ($("select.goog-te-combo option:first").val()=='')
     {


         $("select.goog-te-combo option:first").text('English');

     }
     }, 1000);
     });

</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

Comment: checkout this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13030153/translate-website-to-any-specific-language-on-page-load

Comment: thanks but i do not know that how to use it #googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE). could you explain me .

Comment: Go to this http://translate.google.com/manager/website/?hl=en add your live website url , select language you need to set , in the last it will give you javascript code follow the instruction and enjoy :) for this you need to login via google account.\

Comment: am passing like this http://localhost/808080/#googtrans(en|TARGET_LANG_CODE) ,but it is not work

Comment: follow the second comment and read carefully.

Comment: thanks ,yes i follow the second comment but it is not working at loading time .it is working if am selecting but i do not need to select i need to its working on loading time

Comment: this is script  <div id="google_translate_element"></div><script type="text/javascript">
function googleTranslateElementInit() {
  new google.translate.TranslateElement({pageLanguage: 'en', includedLanguages: 'ar,en', layout: google.translate.TranslateElement.InlineLayout.SIMPLE}, 'google_translate_element');
}
</script><script type="text/javascript" src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>

Comment: thanks for reply but it not working for me if anyone have idea please help me.

Comment: the redirect link should be this way: http://yourdomain.com/index.html#googtrans(ar|en)